# Encountering an Issue with Oracle ORA-39405 Error

Tags: oracle, backup, migration

I've been researching and testing for days now, and so far, I haven't been able to solve my problem. I'd like to know if any of you have ever encountered this.

I'm facing a challenge with a client's backup. This backup is an Oracle Data Pump, and the client is using Oracle version 19c. I downloaded the same version on my machine through the official Oracle website. However, when trying to recover the database, I encounter a rejection. The reason is a version incompatibility: the destination database (mine) is on version TSTZ 32, while the source database (the client's) is on version TSTZ 42.

I've tried various ways to obtain the TimeZone (TSTZ) file to update my database, but so far, I haven't been successful.

How can I obtain this file for an update? Do I need to have an Oracle license in the cloud to get this file to update my database?

I conducted a search to verify if I had access to the necessary file to update the database, however, I couldn't find it. I tried to download the latest version of Oracle (23c), but without success. Additionally, I explored ways to bypass the need for this file during the repair process, but also without success.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You say `I tried to download the latest version of Oracle (23c), but without success.` - what happened - how did this fail? Did you uninstall your previous version first? What OS are you using? Also, `Additionally, I explored ways to bypass the need for this file during the repair process, but also without success` - what commands, **exactly**, did you issue? The more detail you provide, the better the chance you have of obtaining a good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Timezone version 42 is available as a separate patch (35220732) or as part of the 19.20 Database Release Update (35320081).

A valid support subscription is required to download them from https://support.oracle.com/.

Comment: Is there any way I can get this Patch without the need for a license, as I will only use it to retrieve data from the database?

Comment: You could try the second option mentioned in this article...
https://mikedietrichde.com/2019/05/14/data-pump-the-time-zone-pitfalls/

Comment: I understand... The problem is that unfortunately I don't have access to where the source bank was generated, because the client who sent it to me, wouldn't have any other way?

Comment: Since you do not have access to the source database the client will need to follow the instructions that I posted in my earlier comment to export the data in the TZ you require. 

The only other documented way is for them to send you the patch if they have a license. However, I would guess sharing the patch with you would violate their EULA with Oracle.

Comment: @ThiagoRoque You can not officially download the patch without a contract. However, you can get a patched database another way, for example with Oracle Cloud Free Tier. Or you can download 23c Free, which comes with a version 42 timezone file (but also some limitations, like the limit of 12 GB data in the database).

Comment: In order to obtain Oracle Cloud Free Tier, do I need to pay something after use, and can I cancel after I recover the customer database?

Comment: @ThiagoRoque A credit/debit card is required for registration. You get 300$ cloud credit that you can use for 30 days. The subscription can be cancelled before the need for actual payment. https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/